# Keras - Conv1D layer - Deep understanding

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to understanding the conv layers

`x = Conv1D(256, 3, padding='same', activation="relu")(x)`

For this layer, the shapes of

```
input = (batch_size, 196, 512)
weight = (3, 512, 256)
bias = (256,)
output = (batch_size, 196, 256)
```

For understanding, I am testing the calculation, manually.

I am creating two numpy arrays with shape of the `input` and `weight`,

if the `batch_size = 32`,

```
x = np.ones((32, 196, 512)) # Created an array with shape of input which is feed into the Conv1D layer(x)
weight = np.ones((3, 512, 256)) # Weight of the Conv1D layer(x)
y = np.dot(x, weight) # In every neural network, the y = input*weight+bias
```

The shape of the output `y` is `(1, 196, 3, 256)`. But, the excepted shape is `(32, 196, 256)`

How to understand this manually, thanks

Comment: Convolution != dot product.

Comment: @xdurch0, then, conv1D is matrix multiplication?

Comment: No, convolution is convolution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution